# Select in where condition is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It appears to me that a select statement (that is very fast on its own) is slower than writing the condition explicitly as a string. Here is a dummy example:

The fast version:

```
select *
FROM db.dbo.A
left join db.dbo.B on A.id = B.id
where A.selected_variable in ('XXX','YYY')
```

The slow version:

```
select 
    selected_variable
    into #t_temp
from db.dbo.some_table
where some_condition = 'X'

select *
FROM db.dbo.A
left join db.dbo.B on A.id = B.id
where A.selected_variable in (select selected_variable from #t_temp) -- returns ('XXX','YYY')
```

Does someone knows why and what would be best practice to avoid the performance drop?

Answer (score 2):

I think the performance perspective `EXISTS` is better than the `IN` clause. Since `IN` clause internally convert to `OR` conditions(resulting in more conditions)

Try this script and compare the query execution plan and execution time

```
select *
FROM db.dbo.A
left join db.dbo.B on A.id = B.id
where EXISTS (select 1 
              from db.dbo.some_table t 
              WHERE A.selected_variable = t.selected_variable AND some_condition = 'X')
```

Comment: This depends on the indexes.  You might want to point out what the right indexing is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below version, which avoids additional TempDB IO ( which is reducing the performance).

Also, see if the selected_variable, some_condition in some_table is having proper indexes.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM dbo.A AS A
INNER JOIN DBO.some_table AS s 
ON A.Selected_Variable = s.selected_variable
LEFT JOIN dbo.B AS B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE s.some_condition = 'X'
```